# How to add custom objects to the "add object" menu?

Tags: objects, customization

I want to add things like basic tables/chairs/houses I have made over the past year to my <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> menu. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is an addon called [creaprim](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?256602-Addon-EWOCprojects-presents-CreaPrim) which allows you to do this.

1. Install and enable the addon ([direct download](http://www.ewocprojects.be/object_creaprim.py)). Some people have had issues using this addon in the 2.70, you can find a patched version [here](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?332531-CreaPrim-script-giving-errors-when-used-in-2-70).
2. Select the object which you wish to add to the *Add* menu and press *Create Primitive* in *Tools shelf > Tool > History > CreaPrim*:

   [image]
3. You can now add it from the *Add* menu:

   [image]

Comment: [Here](http://www.ewocprojects.be/object_creaprim.py)'s a direct link to the addon.  Perhaps you could use this instead of directing to the BlenderArtists page?

Answer (score 10):

You could create a group <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd> and set the object's name for each of your objects in *Object Mode*. To add groups to the scene use the *Add Menu* <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>  *Group Instance*.

[image]

In case you would like to add your objects from python to the menu you could use the `add_curve_extra_objects` addon as a template you find it in the Blender installation directory in `2.70/scripts/addons/add_curve_extra_objects` (where 2.70 is the version) see `__init__.py`

Comment: Also, you could create a Blender file that has all the objects you want to see in the *Add Menu*, then when you start with a new blender file, just append from that reference file all the groups.  And just move them all to an unseen layer.

Answer (score 4):

To include your own objects in the add object menu you can create an addon. There are a few example addons available that you can look at, as well as a simple example script available in the python templates of blender's text editor.

While these examples use python code to create new objects you could have your script import an object from another blend file.