# how to add a mesh in blender using script?

Tags: python, scripting

I need to add a mesh using script. I am not asking about adding the primitive objects using the script.

Example: Add a single face with 4 vertices or any simple objects using script.

Comment: See _`templates > python > operator mesh add`_ in the text editor.  Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65129/how-do-i-create-a-script-for-geometry-i-create

Comment: thanks for the help