# UnboundLocalError of writting a file while updating script

Tags: python, scripting, versions

I'm trying to update some old code that worked for 2.79 but I'm trying to update to 2.8. One of the parts of the script involves writing a meta file and using some variables from the script to write it. while testing the script, it keeps giving me errors

The code:

```
     almeta="""fileFormatVersion: 2
guid: """+alguid+"""
timeCreated: 1505499902
licenseType: Free
TextureImporter:
 fileIDToRecycleName: {}
 serializedVersion: 4
 mipmaps:
   mipMapMode: 0
   enableMipMap: 1
   sRGBTexture: 1
   linearTexture: 0
   fadeOut: 0
   borderMipMap: 0
   mipMapsPreserveCoverage: 0
   alphaTestReferenceValue: 0.5
   mipMapFadeDistanceStart: 1
   mipMapFadeDistanceEnd: 3
 bumpmap:
   convertToNormalMap: 0
   externalNormalMap: 0
   heightScale: 0.25
   normalMapFilter: 0
 isReadable: 0
 grayScaleToAlpha: 0
 generateCubemap: 6
 cubemapConvolution: 0
 seamlessCubemap: 0
 textureFormat: 1
 maxTextureSize: """+str(height)+"""
 textureSettings:
   serializedVersion: 2
   filterMode: -1
   aniso: -1
   mipBias: -1
   wrapU: -1
   wrapV: -1
   wrapW: -1
 nPOTScale: 1
 lightmap: 0
 compressionQuality: 50
 spriteMode: 0
 spriteExtrude: 1
 spriteMeshType: 1
 alignment: 0
 spritePivot: {x: 0.5, y: 0.5}
 spriteBorder: {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, w: 0}
 spritePixelsToUnits: 100
 alphaUsage: 1
 alphaIsTransparency: 0
 spriteTessellationDetail: -1
 textureType: 0
 textureShape: 1
 maxTextureSizeSet: 0
 compressionQualitySet: 0
 textureFormatSet: 0
 platformSettings:
 - buildTarget: DefaultTexturePlatform
   maxTextureSize: """+str(height)+"""     
   textureFormat: -1
   textureCompression: 1
   compressionQuality: 50
   crunchedCompression: 0
   allowsAlphaSplitting: 0
   overridden: 0
 spriteSheet:
   serializedVersion: 2
   sprites: []
   outline: []
   physicsShape: []
 spritePackingTag: 
 userData: 
 assetBundleName: 
 assetBundleVariant: 
    
   """        
       
       file=open(path+alguid+"\\asset.meta","w")
       file.write(almeta)
       
       file=open(path+alguid+"\\pathname","w")
       file.write("Assets/"+assetname+"/"+assetname+"_Albedo."+context.scene.my_enum2)
```

and the error I'm getting is:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'height' referenced before assignment

for the line below "- buildTarget: DefaultTexturePlatform":
`maxTextureSize: """+str(height)+"""`

height is declared as:
        `height=image.size[1]`

What I'm getting confused is that why it is a problem when updating blender versions and it is giving an error to the second height variable instead of the first one

I'm new to python coding and any help of fixing the error is appropriated

Comment: Recommend using fstring formatting  rather than string addition example https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/136888/15543  Basically you haven't declared `height` before use.  Please post if and where you are declaring the variable `height` in script above.

Comment: Extending from batFINGER, please remember to escape `{}` if you're going to use fstring. There does contain some in your string. Using `{{}}` to escape the literal behavior.

Comment: I declared the height variable as ```        height=image.size[1]``` before the code posted

Comment: Without the whole code this is a guessing game, for instance copying - pasting - running code as is produces same error for `alguid`   Hard to see how this has anything to do with the blender python API apart from it being run as a python script from blender.  making it a candidate for closing as off-topic for being a python run-time error. Suggest making a minimum working example by  editing code to  declare some dummy values  eg `height = 33.33; alguid="Foo"` etc. Often doing this pops out the solution..