# Manually created object to python script in EDIT MODE

Tags: modeling

I manually created an object, and then, in edit mode, I rebuild same object, at cursor position. there I'm using existing geometry to find the best way to rebuild it. but I could do a copy of the result of the vertices list (and other list about faces and edges) and rebuild the mesh from this. so this is a quick way to create an object from edit mode after...
here is the script I did

```
import bpy, bmesh
from bpy import context

cao = context.object
me = cao.data
l =len(me.vertices)
loc = context.scene.cursor.location

v_coords = [ (v.co) for v in me.vertices] 

faces_verts_idx = [face.vertices[:] for face in me.polygons]
edges_verts_idx = [edge.vertices[:] for edge in me.edges]  

edges = [tuple(x+l for x in tup) for tup in edges_verts_idx]
faces = [tuple(x+l for x in tup) for tup in faces_verts_idx]

# new vert at curs pos    
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
mw = cao.matrix_world
new_verts = [bm.verts.new(mw.inverted()@coord + loc) for coord in v_coords]
bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()
for tup in edges:
    bm.edges.new((bm.verts[tup[0]], bm.verts[tup[1]]))

for tup in faces:
    vert_tup=()
    for i in tup:
        vert_tup += (bm.verts[i],)
    bm.faces.new(vert_tup)
for v in bm.verts:
    v.select = True
bm.select_flush(True)
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
me.update()
bpy.ops.mesh.remove_doubles()
bpy.ops.mesh.normals_make_consistent(inside=False)
```

[image]

this is working, but on more advanced meshes, some faces are inverted,
and the part on the mesh rebuild seems clumsy. not sure there is not a much simpler way, under bmesh, to do this.

Comment: ok the guy get a serious problem with me lol I don't care

Answer (score 2):

**Edit mode Dupe.**

*Not 100% sure on if this is what you want since the question code bunks out after one copy*

**EDIT.**

Given comment and OP's answer Q is pretty much a dupe of

[How do I Create a script for geometry I create?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65129/how-do-i-create-a-script-for-geometry-i-create)

which for example, could  be converted to a generic add primitive operator,

[image]

To make an copy at cursor location Would simply just read in the mesh again using `from_mesh` and translate the appended verts.  Test Script, with result as illustrated in GIF.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

from bpy import context

scene = context.scene
ob = context.edit_object
mwi = ob.matrix_world.inverted()
me = ob.data

loc = scene.cursor.location

bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
n = len(bm.verts)

# read again
bm.from_mesh(me)
bmesh.ops.translate(
        bm,
        verts=bm.verts[n:],
        vec=mwi @ scene.cursor.location
        )
        
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

Comment: kind of. interesting.
the goal behind was to have the geometry usable in a script (maybe copied to a file) that you can add later in edit mode. it could be an addon using UI list... I put an answer using bm.from_mesh(me) too. as someone suggested me on blender chat

Comment: ok I copy this before it's erased

Answer (score 0):

add an object (a cone), go to edit mode
then copy geometry with the commented lines and past the result
change cursor location and run the script

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from bpy import context
from mathutils import Vector

edit_obj = context.edit_object
me = edit_obj.data
loc =context.scene.cursor.location
mw = context.object.matrix_world

#get geo from an existing object

#verts = [vertices.co for vertices in me.vertices]
#print("verts=", verts)#Dbg
#faces = [face.vertices[:] for face in me.polygons]
#print("faces=", faces)#Dbg
#edges = [edge.vertices[:] for edge in me.edges]  
#print("edges=", edges)#Dbg

#past result 

verts = [Vector((0.0, 1.0, -1.0)), Vector((0.19509032368659973, 0.9807852506637573, -1.0)), Vector((0.3826834559440613, 0.9238795042037964, -1.0)), Vector((0.5555702447891235, 0.8314695954322815, -1.0)), Vector((0.7071067690849304, 0.7071067690849304, -1.0)), Vector((0.8314695954322815, 0.5555702447891235, -1.0)), Vector((0.9238795042037964, 0.3826834261417389, -1.0)), Vector((0.9807852506637573, 0.19509035348892212, -1.0)), Vector((1.0, -4.371138828673793e-08, -1.0)), Vector((0.9807852506637573, -0.19509032368659973, -1.0)), Vector((0.9238795638084412, -0.3826833963394165, -1.0)), Vector((0.8314696550369263, -0.5555701851844788, -1.0)), Vector((0.7071067690849304, -0.7071067690849304, -1.0)), Vector((0.5555701851844788, -0.8314696550369263, -1.0)), Vector((0.38268348574638367, -0.9238795042037964, -1.0)), Vector((0.19509030878543854, -0.9807853102684021, -1.0)), Vector((-8.742277657347586e-08, -1.0, -1.0)), Vector((-0.19509024918079376, -0.9807853102684021, -1.0)), Vector((-0.3826834261417389, -0.9238795042037964, -1.0)), Vector((-0.5555703043937683, -0.8314695358276367, -1.0)), Vector((-0.7071067094802856, -0.7071068286895752, -1.0)), Vector((-0.8314694762229919, -0.5555704236030579, -1.0)), Vector((-0.9238795042037964, -0.38268357515335083, -1.0)), Vector((-0.9807852506637573, -0.1950903832912445, -1.0)), Vector((-1.0, 1.1924880638503055e-08, -1.0)), Vector((-0.9807852506637573, 0.1950904130935669, -1.0)), Vector((-0.9238794445991516, 0.3826836049556732, -1.0)), Vector((-0.831469714641571, 0.5555700659751892, -1.0)), Vector((-0.70710688829422, 0.7071067094802856, -1.0)), Vector((-0.5555703043937683, 0.8314695954322815, -1.0)), Vector((-0.3826834261417389, 0.9238795638084412, -1.0)), Vector((-0.19509023427963257, 0.9807853102684021, -1.0)), Vector((0.0, 0.0, 1.0))]
faces = [(0, 32, 1), (1, 32, 2), (2, 32, 3), (3, 32, 4), (4, 32, 5), (5, 32, 6), (6, 32, 7), (7, 32, 8), (8, 32, 9), (9, 32, 10), (10, 32, 11), (11, 32, 12), (12, 32, 13), (13, 32, 14), (14, 32, 15), (15, 32, 16), (16, 32, 17), (17, 32, 18), (18, 32, 19), (19, 32, 20), (20, 32, 21), (21, 32, 22), (22, 32, 23), (23, 32, 24), (24, 32, 25), (25, 32, 26), (26, 32, 27), (27, 32, 28), (28, 32, 29), (29, 32, 30), (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31), (30, 32, 31), (31, 32, 0)]
edges = [(0, 1), (0, 32), (32, 1), (1, 2), (32, 2), (2, 3), (32, 3), (3, 4), (32, 4), (4, 5), (32, 5), (5, 6), (32, 6), (6, 7), (32, 7), (7, 8), (32, 8), (8, 9), (32, 9), (9, 10), (32, 10), (10, 11), (32, 11), (11, 12), (32, 12), (12, 13), (32, 13), (13, 14), (32, 14), (14, 15), (32, 15), (15, 16), (32, 16), (16, 17), (32, 17), (17, 18), (32, 18), (18, 19), (32, 19), (19, 20), (32, 20), (20, 21), (32, 21), (21, 22), (32, 22), (22, 23), (32, 23), (23, 24), (32, 24), (24, 25), (32, 25), (25, 26), (32, 26), (26, 27), (32, 27), (27, 28), (32, 28), (28, 29), (32, 29), (29, 30), (32, 30), (30, 31), (32, 31), (31, 0)]

new_verts = [(mw.inverted()@coord + loc) for coord in verts]

new_mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("test")
new_mesh.from_pydata(new_verts, edges, faces)

bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(edit_obj.data)
bm.clear()
bm.from_mesh(new_mesh)
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(edit_obj.data)
```

so this is simple to create your own object copy his geometry in a file to use it later under edit mode.
an add-on could be done from this...