# Is it possible to store our own 3D models in Blender?

Tags: mesh, objects

In Blender we have built-in 3D models (such as Cube, Cone, Suzanne, etc.). These models are placed into the scene by a simple mouse click on a button or a menu item.

Is it possible to use our very own 3D model that can be called when clicking on a specific button in Blender?

Comment: Native UI way using groups instances so it will be Shift+A>Group>Group name. Direct way to add them to menu should be possible with addon, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8275/how-to-add-custom-objects-to-the-add-object-menu