# Second Life - Like Prims in Blender (not sculpties)?

Tags: modeling, scripting, objects

Despite more and more objects in Second Life are made of sculpties or even meshes, SL also has their old-school prims, that can be used for making stuff. While Sculpties are basically spheres, that are transformed into different shapes using an RGB-displacement-map that's translated into world-vectors, Meshes are actual multi-polygon objects, that can be rigged and often used for avatar shapes or clothing.

The old-school prims, for those who don't know them, are instead primitives as we know them in quite every 3D application, means boxes, cylinders, torus, cones ect, that can be arranged into making more complex objects. The benefit of prims are, that they are easy to use. You don't need to fiddle with vertex and meshes, instead you use parameters to change the prim. SL offers not only to scale, rotate, transform them but also to change a fixed set of shaping parameters for their prims. They can be screwed, loop-cut, made hollow and so on. I am now looking for prims like these to use in Blender, for quick creation of simple objects. Not to replace modelling but as an alternative. Is there a plugin for Blender that allows this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/H46n5.jpg

[Edit] Note: I don't want to replace the normal modelling tools in blender with this. Prims are crude and for more complex models not the right tool to chose. Second Life had it mainly for the purpose to somehow measure/limit the usage of objects on a Sim (and thus reducing load on their servers) besides of giving unexperienced users tools to create 3D objects the easy way (lets say for instance a wall with a hole in it for the door or a simple roof (Box with taper modifier).
I just think that there are situations where such a thing could come in handy even in a full-featured modeller like Blender.

Comment: There is no such thing in Blender, as far as I know. At least not after creation if I understand correctly. For generative objects you may look into node based procedural addons, like Sverchok or Animation Nodes

Comment: I think the "prims" in the Add > Mesh menu should suffice. Loop cut is possible in Edit Mode (Ctrl R). Screw can be done with a modifier. And if you want to go carving things without caring about topology there's always the Boolean Modifier. I think if you play with the meshes and tools available in Blender you will soon laugh at the thought of modeling with SL prims. Blender allows many more possibilities.

Comment: @Mentalist as said, I didn't want to replace the SL prims with the powerful tools Blender offers... I wanted them additionally

Comment: You could model desired object and add it into the Shift+A menu [with an addon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8275/how-to-add-custom-objects-to-the-add-object-menu). Not quite sure how many options will be available in the Last Operator panel though

Comment: But then I could not change it's parameters. And prims could produce a ton of possible different single-prim objects. http://www.carlpetersheim.us/3d/images/huron_01_create_prim_014.jpg 
But maybe it would be possible to change them using morphs?